# How can I remove [Online] from biblatex references in IEEE format

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

I'm trying to make a reference in Latex using biblatex, but everytime I give a URL, like in this example:

```
@techreport{autosar_technical_review,
    title = {Technical Overview},
    author = {AUTOSAR},
    date = {2008},
    url = {https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/3-0/AUTOSAR_TechnicalOverview.pdf}
}
```

it shows up like this:

[image: reference with [online]]

I want to remove this [Online], everything else is working alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`biblatex-ieee` adds the "[Online]" marker via the `url` bibstring (cf. [`ieee.bbx`, l. 78 in v1.3f](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/blob/7f67eea42f55ee0c27c8358dd7cd64bf47ad4a4c/ieee.bbx#L78)), so we can get rid of it by redefining this bibstring

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  url         = Available ,
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{autosar_technical_review,
  title  = {Technical Overview},
  author = {AUTOSAR},
  date   = {2008},
  url    = {https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/3-0/AUTOSAR_TechnicalOverview.pdf}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,autosar_technical_review,ctan}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: AUTOSAR, ‘Technical overview,’ Tech. Rep., 2008. Available: https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/3-0/AUTOSAR_TechnicalOverview.pdf.]

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem!